# The word of "where" starts a clause that is not place-related

Tags: conjunctions

[Robot Visions](https://novelfreereadonline.com/robot-visions/stories-robot-visions-993740)

> Genetic engineering has been used imaginatively to restore wildlife
> **where** related species existed in zoos or as pets. Pollution is a thing
> of the past.

Why did here use "where" rather than "which"?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it should be which?

Comment: Have you considered the role of the relative word in the relative clause?

Comment: There are ***many*** contexts ***where*** the word "where" is used metaphorically in ways that are neither literally nor obviously "place-related". That's a sentence where I did it ("spatial" metaphor), just as much as it's a sentence ***in which*** I did it ("container" metaphor).

Answer (score 2):

It is meaning 5 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/where#Conjunction) (it marks this meaning as "Law" but it is much more widely used than just legal contexts):  "in a position, case, etc., in which".

Here you could write it as "in cases in which" . You could not use "which" on its own, because the antecedent ("cases" etc) is not expressed, but *which* normally needs an explicit antecedent. (It sometimes refers to the whole of the preceding clause, but that is not the case here)